# alternative to Javascript Narcissus engine

Tags: javascript

Are there any pure Javascript alternatives to Narcissus for running Javascript in a web browser? ( Narcissus is the Javascript interpreter written in Javascript itself and is made by the inventor or Javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [List of ECMAScript engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines), but Narcissus seems to be the only one implemented using JavaScript.

Comment: Ok thanks. I need the engine written in javascript so that I can run it in the browser